# DropDownList from IEnumerable<string> model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a IEnumerable list model containing different city names, I would like to make a DropDownList from this model, I saw an example that work, but for creating  links, I think we can do the same thing for a Dropdownlist by looping through the list.  How could I do that ?

```
@model IEnumerable<string>





    @foreach (var link in Model)
    {
      // ????
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the htmlhelper that is already available for you

```
@Html.DropDownList("cities", new SelectList(Model))
```

Comment: He has specifically asked for an iterative method. It sounds like he's already looked at HtmlHelpers.

Comment: The title says he wants a dropdownlist from an ienumerable, so why build a loop if there's a helper that will do the same thing.

Comment: This will result in an error. the Model is an IEnumerable, while Html.DropDownList require SelectList.

Comment: Yes Segev, that's why I can't do it. It is an IEnumerable<string>.

Comment: I downvoted because it is a generic answer to the title of the question that completely ignores the specification of the question itself in favour of a rapid answer to achieve upvotes.

Comment: @AntP it's not an upvote I'm after, maybe you are with that? I don't wanna be harsh but you started it. If you look into my posts, you will see a lot of them goes into great lengths and why? Because I believe in what SO promotes. **A wiki site with excellent content.** But sometimes, a question can be answered in such a short way because it's so simple. So before you say something like that to somebody, go and check their profile first and their answers. I'm not after popularity you know. I'm just here to help.

Comment: And for the sake of good camaraderie I upvoted your answer as it's correct anyway - a good option to the OP's problem. I will upvote you 10 times, if I can, to show that I'm not afraid that you'll get more points than me. ;)

Comment: @Segev-CJ-Shmueli yes I missed that so I changed my answer and added the SelectList. But it's far from being a downvoted answer because it's stupid ain't it. I will leave this answer here so all this talking is preserve so others can be reminded what a downvote should be and not just be trigger happy. Also to remind people here that you join SO not to run for popularity but to help this great site help others.

Comment: @vonv I have read a lot of your other answers, as a lot of them are on MVC, and many of them are very good answers. This one, however, I felt missed the point of the question slightly as the OP stated quite clearly that he was looking for an alternative, iterative method. Anyway, your answer has improved significantly so I have retracted the downvote.

Comment: @AntP no harm done ;) It's just that when I read a question and it has **not** been explicitly stated that he has NOT tried what I suggested, then I suggest it, especially if it offers a better alternative. I guess you've seen that in my answers. I'm here to educate too, if I can, you know share what I've learned from other people and from experience. In this question, yes I agree the OP is looking for an alternative. But it's clear that there's no mention he has tried the htmlhelper already, so I thought, the OP just thought it's not possible with the html helper.

Comment: Oh wow, a lot of chatter after the downvote. I did not meant to hurt anybody's feelings, I downvoted an answer because it was wrong at the time I voted for it. Though I could edit it for you, I don't believe in editing wrong responses because often they represent common mistakes and I believe keeping them there is adding value. It might have been an oversight on your behalf,and you have corrected it since so I will find out how to reverse my vote; But I still stand behind my vote at the time, and the importance of me rendering that vote at that time.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use HtmlHelpers, which, from your question, it sounds like you don't, you can use the following iterative method for an `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
<select name="myFormInputName">
@foreach (var link in Model)
{
  <option value="@(link)">@(link)</option>
}
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternative.

Comment: Your answer is not wrong per se, but with the resource .NET allow us I feel that it's far from being correct!
When using IEnumerable, Array, list, dictionary, or any enumerated structure in general you ought to use the DropDownList. There is absolutely no argument against it, and way too many pros in terms of project maintenance to use id .

Comment: @Segev-CJ-Shmueli except, when the question quite specifically states that the asker doesn't want to use HtmlHelpers but in fact wants an alternative that "*loops through the list*," suggesting HtmlHelpers in return would be an inherently poor answer that ignores the question.

Answer (score 3):

The very simple, and basic form (without moving the SelectList to the controller) is :

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
@{
var selectList = new SelectList(Model) ;

}

@Html.DropDownList("MyDropDownListName", selectList)
```

Although I would prefer creating an extension to the HtmlHelper class, or using a "strong named" dropdownlist  `@Html.DropDownListFor(myvar=>myvar.City, selectList)`